# Downloading maven libs

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build, jar

Every time I build any of new projects with jar file (`mvn install`) maven download libs from it's repository into root of projects
How pom looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.strings</groupId>
    <artifactId>FindStrings</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

What libs maven download you can see on screenshot (all besides `src`)
[image]

As I can understand those libs maven use to build project (for correct work of maven plugins), so can I set path for maven to not download libs every time for new project and not to litter in the root of project? Thanks

P.S. Environment variables (M2, M2_HOME) were installed

Comment: You need to define all the jar as a dependencies in  `pom.xml` file, but  also I don't understand how your maven knows about those jars to download ?

Comment: There is definitively something wrong ,cause the downloads should go into `$HOME/.m2/repository` instead and never in your project....

Comment: What does your `settings.xml` contain?

Comment: @Ros5292, maven has it's own repositories to fetch libs to run it's goals with plugins and also know how to get them by plugin name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a path in the **`setting.xml`** to your **`local repository`**. Once the path is provided and you run `maven install` command,  maven downloads the libraries & jar from its central repository to its local repository path. And henceforth, if the same libraries or jar is needed, maven instead of downloading the jars & libraries again, it access those from the local repo path.

Answer (score 0):

Ruslan in comments brought me to the right thought. I checked settings.xml and there was no path to the maven local repository. My issue fixed by adding right path to it.